# Rails - Getting Started guide - Error (We're sorry but something went wrong)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a problem with Rails. 
I was following the getting started guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) when I arrived to the point 5.6 I got an error: I ran **rails server** and I called http://localhost:3000/articles/new through my browser but I received as message "We're sorry but something went wrong".

I tried to check the log in order to understand which is the problem but there's no information about errors in the log file.

The error is related to the resource articles, because calling /welcome/index works correctly.

Some details: Rails 4.2.0, ruby 1.9.3p392, sqlite 3.8.5.
Here the project: https://github.com/agastaldoDataxu/rails_wa

There are other articles in stackoverflow talking about this error, but I cannot find any solutiuon.

Thanks,
Ale

Comment: Surely there is sth in logs. Check `logs/development`. There is really no way to guess what happened.

Comment: This is what I can find in the log:

Started GET "/articles/new" for ::1 at 2015-01-21 09:51:36 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

Comment: Can you add more lines from your log file to your question? eg the top 100 lines.  I bet the answer is in there.

Comment: @MaxWilliams please see here: https://github.com/alessiogastaldo/rails_wa/blob/patch-1/development.log

Answer (score 0):

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/article/new"):
```

you are calling /article/new .  Try calling /articles/new

Comment: That was a typo and I got a route error calling article. 
The problem is when I call articles or articles/new

Comment: did you run  " rake db:migrate "   ?

Comment: Yes I did. Do I have to start sqlite3 as service? Or does it run with the command **rails server** ?

Comment: yes, it will. You have it specified in the gemfile right ?

Comment: Yes. Here you can find the project details https://github.com/agastaldoDataxu/rails_wa

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this solution on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670968/rails-4-exception-stack-traces-dont-show-in-development), but this issue was solved for me by adding

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

to my controllers. Solution found in [this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11063#issuecomment-25944482).